# can increase number for string using for loop? Android studio

Tags: android, database, for-loop, android-sqlite

is there any way can do a loop for string?
This is my Database data. I can't use Int because It won't allow 0 to be the first character.

**This is my data.** I have two tables. "**Donation_Details**" TxnNo data comes from "**Information**" 'unitcode + lastTxnNo'

[image: Database img]

How to increase the number to be '0012' after I click the button save? I have to check every single time when users click the button save, It will auto increase automatically, to make sure the user know how many transaction have been created.

**this is my CODE.**

```
 BigDecimal paidAmt = new BigDecimal(D_Amount.getText().toString()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                Model txn = new Model();  // initialize your model class first
                txn.setName(D_Name.getText().toString());
                //txn.setTxnNo(D_Txn.getText().toString());
                txn.setTxnDate(Select_Date.getText().toString());
                txn.setAmount(paidAmt);
                txn.setDescription1(D_Description.getSelectedItem().toString());
                txn.setDescription2(Ds_Description.getText().toString());
                try {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name", txn.getName());  // get the entered name here.
                    //cv.put("TxnNo", txn.getTxnNo());
                    cv.put("TxnDate", txn.getTxnDate());
                    cv.put("Amount", txn.getAmount().toPlainString());
                    cv.put("Description1", txn.getDescription1());
                    cv.put("Description2", txn.getDescription2());
                    db.insert("Donation_Details", null, cv);
                    db.close();
                    Toast.makeText(Donation_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
cv.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", txn.getTxnNo()));
```

It will have a zero-padding with a length of 4.

**Edit**

```
int i; // declare as global value

Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
       i = ++i;
       txn.setTxnNo(i);
       cv.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", txn.getTxnNo()));
    }
 });
```

---

To prevent the number back to 0 , you need to use `SharedPreferences`.

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity1.this);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
 int i = app_preferences.getInt("key",0);  

 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
 clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {       
           i = ++i;
           txn.setTxnNo(i+"");   // set to Model class
           cv.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", txn.getTxnNo()));    // save to database and padding 0 to left
           editor.putInt("key",i).commit();          
        }
     });
```

Comment: What I want is make it to auto increment... If using String, it won't work?

Comment: The above code will only work if you not closing your app. After close, it will start from 0 again.

Comment: what is your ++i?

Comment: ohhh. I want to save it into database

Comment: I try first. Thank you  @John Joe

Comment: If you not closing your app, did the auto-increment worked ?

Comment: I'm using `cv.put("TxnNo", txn.getTxnNo());` the Txn.getTxnNo is a OOP. how do I apply it at your code?

Comment: But the line "txn.setTxnNo(i)" says, String in Model cannot be applied to (int).... And I can't put it "toString". Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: where you add the `.toString()` ? Can you post full line ?

Comment: Because In my database. My TxnNo is a String. So that i is an Integer. Two can't be applied. `txn.setTxnNo(i);`

Comment: the setTxnNo is a String. (i) is a integer. Two can't be applied.

Comment: how about `txn.setTxnNo(i+");` ?

Comment: I doesn't work, But I suddenly think others way might work. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to make it constantly increase instead of back to 0? @John Joe

Comment: OMG!! It works... You are really professional. Thank you very much, My friend.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. Can you do me a favor? I don't know how to apply shared preference In my latest code... I updated the latest code below your code... can you help me? @John Joe

Comment: @LeonZaii Sorry I don't get you.

Comment: Consider add a new post by providing more information

Comment: This is my new post... Thanks [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549597/how-to-make-the-number-stay-in-the-latest-number-instead-of-going-back-to-the-de) @John Joe

Comment: can you please refer there and help me to solve this problem? @John Joe

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using shared preference,

in your case, initialise an int value,

```
int id;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("data-Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key",id++);
editor.commit();
```

now, to get that value using preference,

```
id=sharedpreferences.getInt("key", 0);
```

this way you don't need to care about your id.

Comment: I have already applied autoincrement. apply it to your requirement. id is the value every time gets updated. because I've incremented it whenevr i'm saving it on sharedprefs.

Comment: There is an Error at your code "id++" if I use. I have updated the latest database design. please refer the more clearly design...

Answer (score 0):

in case you just want to increase the value of the integer just do this

```
String num = /*get the value from db*/;
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num+"");
num = num1+"";
//then save the string num to the db.
```

but if u want to save the value in the device the sahred preferences is the way to go.

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("valuestorage", 0); // 0 - for private mode
String num = /*get the value from db*/;
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num+"");
num = num1+"";
pref.edit().putString("lastno",num).apply();
//then save the string num to the db.
```

now you need not call the database everytime only call it if the pref value is null.

so now you'll check the value from pref increment it and save it in db again.

here is how:
**considering the data is present in pref**

```
String aa = pref.getString("lastno","");
if(!aa.equals(""))
{
String num = aa;
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num+"");
num = num1+"";
pref.edit().putString("lastno",num).apply();
//then save the string num to the db.
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences