# how to make the number stay in the latest number instead of going back to the default?

Tags: android

my TxnNo(A0010001) came from Unitcode(A001) + LastTxnNo(0001).  This is my button click.

```
Db_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Model txn = new Model();// initialize your model class first
                BigDecimal paidAmt = new BigDecimal(D_Amount.getText().toString()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                txn.setName(D_Name.getText().toString());
                txn.setTxnNo(D_Txn.getText().toString());
                txn.setTxnDate(Select_Date.getText().toString());
                txn.setAmount(paidAmt);
                txn.setDescription1(D_Description.getSelectedItem().toString());
                txn.setDescription2(Ds_Description.getText().toString());

                try {

                    SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name", txn.getName());
                    cv.put("TxnNo", txn.getTxnNo());
                    cv.put("TxnDate", txn.getTxnDate());
                    cv.put("Amount", txn.getAmount().toPlainString());
                    cv.put("Description1", txn.getDescription1());
                    cv.put("Description2", txn.getDescription2());
                    db.insert("Donation_Details", null, cv);
                    db.close();
                    increaseNumber++;
                    populate_TxnNo();
                    Toast.makeText(Donation_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
```

I put `increaseNumber++;` to make sure it will increase automatically. So Everytime I click the button. the number will change "A0010001" to "A0010002" and so on. But once I leave this page, and go in again. It will back to "A0010001". How to make it stay at the latest number instead of going back to "A0010001". 
**This is the method to set the numbering.**

```
 private void populate_TxnNo() {

        int lastNumber = Integer.valueOf(txn.getLastTxnNo());
        lastNumber = lastNumber + increaseNumber;
        String stringLast = String.format("%04d", lastNumber);
        String txnNo = txn.getUnit_Code() + stringLast;
        //increaseNumber++;
        D_Txn.setText(txnNo);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

So for me to understand the **Shared preference**  I put those code to the button new.

```
Db_New.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                increaseNumber++;
                populate_TxnNo();

            }
        });
```

But I don't know how to use **Shared preference** even though I see the example of code... Can anyone explain it for me?  How to use this code?

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        edit=prefs.edit();  
edit.putString("yourKey", txnNo);
            edit.commit();  

String txnNo = prefs.getString("yourKey", null);
```

Comment: You need to examine the scope of `increaseNumber`.  My guess is that you're defining it someplace where it does not persist between onclick events.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `But once I leave this page` ... I interpret this to mean leaving the current _activity_.

Comment: You're probably going to have to use shared preferences here, or maybe SQLite, to store the UI state.  Then, when you return to the activity, you can reload the number value.

Comment: shared preferences? how to use it into my code? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Just take 5 minutes and search Stack Overflow; you should find a ton of stuff.  There is also the possibility to save the instance state of your activity, but that generally would only be reliable to preserve your selections across device rotations, not changing activities.

Comment: noted... Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: which button you want to use increment ? `Db_New` or `Db_Save` ?

Comment: I'm done with increment. There is only one problem is when I quit the activity and go in again it will go back. means It need shared preference.

Comment: When click **Db_New**, the **LastTxnNo** will increase. @John Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, declare these two variables

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int count;
```

Next add these in `onCreate` method

```
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("counters", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
count = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter", 0);
```

Finally modify `populate_TxnNo` methods

```
  private void populate_TxnNo() {

        int a = count++;
        int lastNumber = Integer.valueOf(txn.getLastTxnNo());
        lastNumber = lastNumber + a;
        String stringLast = String.format("%04d", lastNumber);
        String txnNo = txn.getUnit_Code() + stringLast;
        D_Txn.setText(txnNo);
        editor.putInt("counter", ++a);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: the `SharedPreferences` can't put at the `onCreate`. So I put Outside the `onCreate`. But when I Open the activity. It crash... So it's not working

Comment: what is the  logcat said?

Comment: I don't know. I think the SharedPreferences can't put at outside the `onCreate` But if I put in `onCreate` method. the editor can't be used... @John Joe

Comment: You should learn how to read stacktrace.Without stacktrace, it is hardly  for me to fix the issues. @LeonZaii

Comment: it says `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.waiku.ebosscharitysystem/com.example.waiku.ebosscharitysystem.Donation_Page}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference` @John Joe

Comment: Still the same. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.waiku.ebosscharitysystem/com.example.waiku.ebosscharitysystem.Donation_Page}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference` with `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` @John Joe

Comment: I've put the pictures into your code. You can check it...  @John Joe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181056/discussion-between-john-joe-and-leon-zaii).

Answer (score 1):

Try using Shared Preference

these two lines before `onCreate()`

```
 SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
```

these two lines in `onCreate()`

```
prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            edit=prefs.edit();
```

and on onPause()  save the string

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    edit.putString("yourKey", txnNo);
    edit.commit();
}
```

and to access it back simply write   in onStart

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        String txnNo = prefs.getString("yourKey", null);
    }
```

Comment: those lines "yourPrefsKey" and "yourKey" are whatever I name it also can?

Comment: where is the onPause()? @Kevin Kurien

Comment: @Leon Zaii yes you can put any thing in it

Comment: It is an inbuilt method just like onCreate and onstart

Comment: So what should I do only copy your code and put inside of my method "populate_TxnNo". replace it to all of my code? @Kevin Kurien

Comment: I've updated my code inside your code. Please help me to check it whether it is correct or not... Thanks... @Kevin Kurien

Comment: @LeonZaii I have edited my answer . Try it and see if it works

Comment: How you create the onPause?

Comment: onPause is an inbuilt method just like onCreate. It is called when the current activity is paused i.e when you leave the application and it is present in the recent apps the your app is in pause state. When you access from the recents then another inbuilt method onResume is called . Search them out the top sites will explain it much clearly

Comment: But it seems have problem if I copy your onPause. I should add super. inside. Is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

simply add **yourNumber** to `shared preferences`

```
int yourNumber;

SharedPreferences number = getSharedPreferences("number", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to save your number

```
number.edit.putInt("number",yourNumber).apply;
```

and read the number next time

```
int savedNumber = number.getInt("number",0);
```